# Google Play Services is required, but Google Play (market) is not installed .. what to do?

Tags: android, distribution, google-play, google-play-services

We want to distribute our application in China, but we currently have a **BIG** issue.

The application requires *Google Play Services* installed. It normally works well: the user is prompted a dialog, and the brought to the *Google Play* application where he can install the *Google Play Services* application.

**And in China?** When an Android phone is bought in mainland China, it usually **does not have Google Play installed**. And it stays that way, users usually never download the Google Play application (see [here](http://www.techinasia.com/chinese-apps-bypassing-google-play-store-for-android/) and [there](http://www.techinasia.com/8-android-app-stores-china/)).

So what we are trying to do is: when we detect that the user does not have Google Play installed, we send him to an URL where he can download the Google Play Services APK directely. But *- as expected -*  we could not find stable url where the apk is available for download.

Did any of you encountered the same kind of problems? How did you resolve it? If not do you have ideas, suggestions? Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thank you!

Comment: If the devices aren't Google certified and doesn't come with Google Play from the manufacturer, I am pretty sure it won't work with installing just the Google Play APK, as it used to rely on other builtin Google-dependencies in a Google-certified device.

Comment: What do you need the Play services for? Did you look for an alternative way of accomplishing the goal?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. We need it because we're using the Google Maps API. And we don't want to install Google Play, but Google Play **Services**.

Comment: I need it for YouTube! aaaaagh

Comment: @user462990 check the accepted answer ;) hope it helps!

Comment: what is the reason for not having google play installed on the chinese phones?

Comment: @numan because the Chinese builders will ship devices without google play, and instead will set their own Android markets. Besides, Google Play is not popular at all in China, they prefer to use Chinese Android markets like Himarket, nduo, etc. there are at least 10 widely used Android markets in China, this is insane :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a late Answer, and contained in a comment I already posted to an answer posted by @johlo, but to clarify things I'll write here what we did that "worked" in the hope that it helps somebody. Don't hesitate to comment for clarifications.

> I actually found a very ugly way of installing google play services: if the user does not have google play we use an URL to download the Google Play Services APK.. That's the best we could do ..

Comment: I think Google Play Services is proprietary and it's against the law to distribute it in such a manner... it might get you into trouble.

Answer (score 3):

The *Google Play Services* APK is only available from the *Google Play Store* and doesn't support installation on devices without the store app, see http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

Depending on what kind of functionality you use from the Google Play Service APK you would need to use a 3rd party API or implement it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) actually we are depending on the Google Play Services because our application is running the Google Maps API. And we need that API, because basically all of our application is about maps. Are there others map libraries that are as complete and precise as google maps?

Comment: I'm sure you know more about the different map alternatives out there, have you looked at OpenStreetMap through something like osmdroid? http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android
http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

Comment: Well the issue is that it would require us a lot of work (investigation and implementation). But that's a good idea, will keep it close thanks ;). I actually found a _very ugly_ way of installing google play services: if the user does not have google play we use an URL to download the Google Play Services APK.. That's the best we could do ..

Answer (score 2):

Add latest Google Play Services APK to your site and download it from your client app, then tell users to install it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to Google Maps API which is part of the NOGAPPS-Projekt.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1715375

Answer (score 0):

Use this method, it'll be helpful.

```
public void checkGooglePlayServices(){
    // Check status of Google Play Services
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    // Check Google Play Service Available
    try{
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10).show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: GooglePlayServiceUtil: ", "" + e);
    }
}
```